# Twisted proxy for proxies

Tags: python, proxy, twisted

I have list of proxies.

I want to write server (based on Twisted) which can connect user to random proxy from my list. So for example i have these list of proxies:

```
187.17.19.156:48111
201.173.81.110:43542
183.245.147.14:80
183.245.147.138:80
93.174.55.82:8080
```

My server IP is 55.55.55.55:1234
When user using my server as proxy than my server will redirect any traffic to one of the proxy from list.

Right now i'm ending up with code like that. But cant get response back and cant switching proxies dynamic.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint
from twisted.internet import reactor


class ServerProtocol(Protocol):

    def dataReceived(self,data):
        print("REquest" + str(data))

        def clientProtocol():
            return ClientProtocol(data)
        endpoint = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, "127.0.0.1", 80)
        endpoint.connect(Factory.forProtocol(clientProtocol))


class ClientProtocol(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, dataToSend):
        self.dataToSend = dataToSend

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write(self.dataToSend)

    def dataReceived(self,data):
        print("Reply" + str(data))

reactor.listenTCP(3333,
                  Factory.forProtocol(ServerProtocol))
reactor.run()
```

Does it even possible to implement?